# Remove $ from JSON Object - possible?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
    alphabet: {
        '$': {
            id: '11',
            href: 'abc'
        },
        mydata: [[Object]],
        status: ['22']
    }
}
```

Is it possible to remove the `$` somehow so the object looks like this:

```
{
    alphabet: {
        id: '11',
        href: 'abc'
        mydata: [[Object]],
        status: ['22']
    }
}
```

I'm new to JavaScript and Node JS, and struggling to figure this out. I tried `delete object.$;` but it does not do anything. I'm pretty sure that I misunderstood this function.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: alphabet: {
        {
            id: '11',
            href: 'abc'
        },
        mydata: [[Object]],
        status: ['22']
    } is invalid. Object stores values in key:value pair

Comment: Thanks. what would be the correct way removing the '$'?

Comment: You have to construct a new Object From this object as you need..

Comment: You will need to find a way to "flatten" the alphabet component of your object. There might be libraries if you fail to do it on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Clone `$` and use `object.assign` to merge clone and original object

```js
var obj = {
    alphabet: {
        '$': {
            id: '11',
            href: 'abc'
        },
        mydata: [''],
        status: ['22']
    }
};

var clone = obj.alphabet["$"];
delete obj.alphabet["$"];
Object.assign(obj,clone);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean put `$` object into the root object.

If the key name is always `$`, you could get the key-value in `$` object as below:

```
let alphabet: {
  '$': {
    id: '11',
    href: 'abc'
  },
  mydata: [[Object]],
  status: ['22']
}

for (let key in alphabet['$']) {
  alphabet[key] = alphabet['$'][key]

  // maybe you should consider the duplicate key.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will loop through the properties of a property in an object and flatten it.

```
function flattenProp(obj, prop) {
  var key;

  for(key in obj[prop]) {
    obj[key] = obj[prop][key];
  }

  delete obj[prop];
};
```

Below is an example of it being used.

```js
var data = {
    alphabet: {
        '$': {
            id: '11',
            href: 'abc'
        },
        mydata: [[Object]],
        status: ['22']
    }
};

console.log(data);

flattenProp(data.alphabet, '$');

console.log(data);

function flattenProp(obj, prop) {
  var key;
  
  for(key in obj[prop]) {
    obj[key] = obj[prop][key];
  }
  
  delete obj[prop];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is quite simple -

```
var obj = {
    alphabet: {
        '$': {
            id: '11',
            href: 'abc'
        },
        mydata: [[Object]],
        status: ['22']
    }
}

var temp = obj.alphabet.$

//copies the internal object to main one
for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(temp).length;i++) {
    obj.Object.keys(temp)[0] = temp[Object.keys(temp)[0]];
}

delete obj.alphabet.$ //remove the old object from it
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.
Assuming your data variable (JSON) is named "data":

```
var data = JSON.parse("your json string");
```

so data looks like this:

```
var data = {
    alphabet: {
        '$': {
            id: '11',
            href: 'abc'
        },
        mydata: [[Object]],
        status: ['22']
    }
}
```

We just need to iterate over `data.alphabet.$`, store all its properties to its parent (`data.alphabet`) and then delete `data.alphabet.$`:

```
for(var propname in data.alphabet["$"]) {
   var propvalue = data.alphabet["$"][propname];

   data.alphabet[propname] = propvalue;
}

delete data.alphabet.$;
```

here's a snippet:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(`{
    "alphabet": {
        "$": {
           "id": "11",
           "href": "abc"
        },
        "mydata": {},
        "status": ["22"]
    }
}`)

for(var propname in data.alphabet["$"]) {
   var propvalue = data.alphabet["$"][propname];
       
   data.alphabet[propname] = propvalue;
}
    
delete data.alphabet.$;

document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}</pre>`
```